# Access the Shift-Insert clipboard from script

Tags: linux, scripting, clipboard

How do I access the Shift-Insert (paste) clipboard from a script? You can see what I use [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/sys.txt).

**Edit**: A demonstration how it works, with `xclip`:

```
echo hello | xclip -selection secondary
xclip -o -selection secondary
```

**Edit 2**: Just implemented the solution below. This will make my life so much easier so I thought I'd share it.

First, the script `pst`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo -n `xclip -d ":0" -o -selection clipboard`
```

then, in `.emacs`:

```
(defun pst ()
 "Inserts the X clipboard (xclip -d :0 -o -selection clipboard) at
point. `M-1' (the '(1)) to insert in the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "pst" '(1))
  (end-of-line) )
```

Now, in any tty, paste with `pst`, in Emacs (anywhere, but specifically in a tty, as in X, you already have Shift-Insert) `M-x pst`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xclip` will allow you to access the PRIMARY, SECONDARY, and CLIPBOARD selections, choosing which one with the `-selection` option.